# Laravel 5 Trying to get property of non-object email

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5, mailgun

I have mail code written in my signup function , and i am receiving this error

> ErrorException in 7c8c0426cb92aba181a5916d6b3e33a6 line 2:
>   Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Users/aliayaz/Adcells-master/resources/views/emails/register-activate.blade.php)

```
        Mail::queueOn('Email-Activation', 'emails.register-activate', $data, function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->to($user->email, $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name);
            $m->subject('Welcome ' . $user->first_name);
        });
```

and i have register-activate file under resources/views/emails

```
@extends('emails/layouts/default')

@section('content')
<p>Hello {{{ $user->first_name }}},</p>

<p>Welcome to SiteNameHere! Please click on the following link to confirm your       SiteNameHere account:</p>

<p><a href="{{{ $activationUrl }}}">{{{ $activationUrl }}}</a></p>

<p>Best regards,</p>

<p>@lang('general.site_name') Team</p>
@stop
```

this code was working flawlessly under laravel 4.2 and i wanted to upgrade to 5.0

> edit 1 :
>   I dont have file named 
>   7c8c0426cb92aba181a5916d6b3e33a6

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue specifically with `Mail::queue` and all it's subset methods. When data is handled via the queue system, it gets serialised, then unserialised when it hits the email view.

However if you were to change your snippet above to `Mail::send` instead, you will find it works.

One approach to handle this is making a site wide decision that only arrays are passed into views.

Comment: yes this has been helpful my error has changed now but its not solved...

now i can send email.. but its not being received... there are no errors..

Comment: I would raise that as a separate question, as it's partially unrelated to this one.

Answer (score 0):

try merging the To & Subject logic in one statement.

```
$m->to($user->email, $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name)->subject('Welcome ' . $user->first_name);
```

Also can you paste the code in this file "7c8c0426cb92aba181a5916d6b3e33a6" to further see what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that $data['user'] exists and is also an object. Probably that's happening. It's trying to get info from $user and it doesn't exists.

Comment: I checked that array contains proper data.. and is putting that data into database properly.. but not in mail

Answer (score 0):

```
 Mail::send('emails.register-activate', $data, function($message) {
  $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('username'))
   ->subject('Verify your email address');
    });
```

if it says input not found the put below code at top of your page

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass array of data inside the view.
You didn't pass $user data inside the view. You have to pass $user variable inside the view. Then only you can access the $user of value

```
    $data = array('user' => $user);

    Mail::queueOn('Email-Activation', 'emails.register-activate', $data, function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->to($user->email, $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name);
        $m->subject('Welcome ' . $user->first_name);
    });
```

then print your view as following

```
    <p>Hello {{{ $user['first_name'] }}},</p>
```